# Is a NULL pointer's dereference also equals NULL?

Tags: c++, pointers, null, dereference

Does the following snippet compile/execute the block in the if-statement?

```
int* pointer = NULL;
int deref = *pointer;
if(deref == NULL){
  // will execute?
}
```

Since the `pointer` variable contains NULL does the dereference of this pointer variable also return NULL or will this result in a runtime error?

Comment: in cannot be dereferenced

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The ISO C standard doesn't impose any requirements like "cannot happen" to the dereferencing of a null pointer. It is undefined behavior, and in fact can be done in some environments and can be provided as a documented language extension (though not a very well considered one, obviously).

Comment: Historically, it has happened that C programmers exploited dereference-able null pointers to simplify the cases in linked list or tree data structures. you can do things like `head_node->next->prev = that` without worrying that `nead_node->next` is the terminating null link. Obviously, that code was found not to be portable to environments that trap null references, oops! It wasn't wrong; it worked fine on the original target platforms, and code was shipped to happy end users. It was **nonportable**.

Comment: @Kaz C is not a mentioned tag - just C++.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc "cannot" isn't entirely correct. It _can_ be done, but the result is undefined.

Comment: Anything could happen because your program exhibits undefined behaviour. By the way: if you are using C++11 prefer nullptr.

Answer (score 3):

The result is "undefined behaviour", which may or may not trigger a runtime error, and should in any case always be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Once you set:

```
int* pointer = NULL;
```

pointer points to nothing. Now when you write this:

```
int deref = *pointer;
```

deref will try to access what pointer points to, which will lead to an **undefined behaviour** like segmentation fault.

I hope this explains.

Answer (score 1):

The current answers addressed the UB very well. However, I want to add something. If you run this code:

```
if(0==NULL){
    std::cout << "True";
}
```

It will prints `True`. So if dereferencing a null pointer on your specific environment leads to returning `0` (which is not a steady case. It is UB), the part inside your if statement will execute.

I just wanted to clarify why it is working on some machines. However, that does not change anything about the fact that it is UB.

Comment: Just pointing out that your example doesn't _dereference_ `NULL`, but the following paragraph _does_ talk about that. What was your intent?

Comment: @JohannGerell I just wanted to inform the OP that his code might work on some machines and execute the instructions inside the if-statement. This behaviour still undefined but some coders may think that it is defined since it is working and behave like theirs intention. So, I see it worth to tell.

Comment: What you're addressing then is the case when the '0' in your example `if(0==NULL)` happens to be the result of dereferencing a null pointer on some platform some time, right? I was confused by how you formulated this.

Comment: Yup exactly that what I meant