# Null assignment

Tags: c, pointers, null

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int *p=NULL;
    *p=30;
    printf("%d %p", *p,p);  //output:- 30 0000
}
```

p should be  pointing to address 0 and I think there should be null assignment error. But how *p is giving output as 30? Is 30 stored in location 0000? According to me 0th address should not be assigned to any variable.

Comment: Dereferencing a null-pointer is undefined, so there is no guarantee that an exception occurs. In this case the code might have been optimized in a way that the pointer is not used at all to store and retrieve the 30, e.g. by storing it in a register, as the code is quite simple. In more complicated situations, a segfault is more likely.

Comment: The behaviour might depend on the optimization settings of the compiler.

Comment: Just undefined behavior, anything can happen

Comment: Related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608081/is-a-null-pointers-dereference-also-equals-null/39608103#39608103

Comment: On what system do you observe this beheaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [..] I think there should be null assignment error.

C staandard doesn't provide any such guarantees.

Dereferencing a null pointer is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So, there's no point in reasoning about why it prints 30.
Btw, you should cast the pointer argument to `void*` to print it:

```
printf("%d %p", *p, (void*)p);
```

Comment: Can you tell me the meaning of the output ? It is giving 30 so it means that *p is changing the value at address 0 to 30 right?

Comment: You are not allowed to dereference a null pointer (`*p = 30;` and in the printf). This usually raises a SIGSEGV on Linux but the behaviour may be different on differnt platforms.
When it's undefined, it's ...undefined. There may be platform specific explanation for why it's 30 on your machine but it's generally useless.

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you tell me why (void *) cast is needed ?

Comment: The C standard requires the argument to match the format specifier (`void*` for `%p`).  See [How to printf a memory address in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30354164/1275169).